# Веб-сервер использующий СУБД Oracle

Tags: oracle, веб-сервер

Доброго времени суток! Есть такая задача построить информационную систему с веб-интерфейсом используя СУБД Оракл, а не типичную для веб-проектов MySQL. Можно ли как-то например пакет джентльменов Денвера перенастроить, чтобы он работал с Ораклом? Если нет, то как собрать все компоненты веб-сервера самому (естественно с СУБД Оракл)? Еще один аспект интересует, повлияет ли это как-то синтаксис php где идет работа с базами данных? (про сам sql не спрашиваю, понятно, что придется использовать особенности pl/sql).

Буду благодарен за исчерпывающие ответы.

Answer (score 1):

1. Веб-сервер -- это сервер, который обрабатывает HTTP-запросы. Apache, nginx, MS IIS -- это веб-сервера. Веб-сервер может запускать сторонние приложения, чтобы обработать HTTP-запрос. Примером служит PHP -- стороннее приложение, которое работает с СУБД, отсюда вывод Веб-серверу без разницы с каким СУБД работает стороннее приложение.
2. Денвер, насколько я помню, это стандартный набор Apache + Php + Mysql ( есть такая штука WAMP ). т.е. он запускает 2 сервера Apache, Mysql и устанавливает php как модуль для Apache.

Поэтому решение такое: нужно установить и запустить Oracle и прочесть информацию http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.oci8.php